# Trying to connect codeanywhere with google compute engine via ssh

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, codeanywhere

codeanywhere provides a public ssh key. i've input it into the metadata and the vm instance in google compute engine, but every time I try to connect from the codeanywhere interface I get an authorization failure and the logs in the instance console have:

yadayada: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

the instance was setup using the cloud launcher with node. I have not done anything else to this instance, it's brand spanking new.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ugh, nevermind. I changed the username in the codeanywhere interface to codeanywhere-ssh-key and it worked.